# C# | Using delegates for instance methods in nested loops

Tags: c#, delegates

suppose we have the following situation:
A dog walker has several customers, where a customer has one or more dogs.

The code for this scenario might look like this:

```cs
public class Dog
{
    public int NeedForWalk { get; set; }
    public int NeedForFood { get; set; }

    public Dog()
    {
    }

    public void TakeForWalk(int walkTime)
    {
        // Taking the dog out will decrease its need for a walk accordingly.
        NeedForWalk -= walkTime;
    }

    public void GiveFood(int amountOfFood)
    {
        // Feeding the dog will decrease its need for food accordingly.
        NeedForFood -= amountOfFood;
    }

}

public class Customer
{
    public IEnumerable<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }

    public Customer()
    {
    }
}

public class DogWalker
{
    public IEnumerable<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    public DogWalker()
    {
    }

    public void walkDogs(int walkTime)
    {
        foreach (Customer customer in Customers)
        {
            foreach (Dog dog in customer.Dogs)
            {
                dog.TakeForWalk(walkTime);
            }
        }
    }

    public void feedDogs(int amountOfFood)
    {
        foreach (Customer customer in Customers)
        {
            foreach (Dog dog in customer.Dogs)
            {
                dog.GiveFood(amountOfFood);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the two methods `walkDogs()` and `feedDogs()` of the `DogWalker` class both implement a similar logic.

If possible, I would like to get rid of the redundancy and use a helper method and delegates to cover this logic at a single point.

The `DogWalker` class could look like this

```cs
public class DogWalker
{
    public IEnumerable<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    public DogWalker()
    {
    }

    public void walkDogs(int walkTime)
    {
        // Use `applyToDogs()` to call `TakeForWalk()` of the `Dog` class for each dog.
    }

    public void feedDogs(int amountOfFood)
    {
        // Use `applyToDogs()` to call `GiveFood()` of the `Dog` class for each dog.
    }

    #region Helper Method
    public void applyToDogs(Func<int> func, IEnumerable<object> listOfArguments)
    {
        foreach (Customer customer in Customers)
        {
            foreach (Dog dog in customer.Dogs)
            {
                // Apply `func` to each dog using the arguments in `listOfArguments`.
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

However, since the methods of the `Dog` class are not static, I am struggling with

- How to correctly implement `applyToDogs()`, maybe even allowing for delegate signatures other than `Func<int>`
- How to then use `applyToDogs()` in the methods `walkDogs()` and `feedDogs()`

Thanks for your help in advance!
I'd greatly appreciate any support on this topic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delegate type can be `Action<Dog, int>`, and you need to bind the instance methods to delegates of such type.

```
public void walkDogs(int walkTime)
{
    applyToDogs(CreateDelegate("TakeForWalk"), walkTime);
}

public void feedDogs(int amountOfFood)
{
    applyToDogs(CreateDelegate("GiveFood"), amountOfFood);
}

public static Action<Dog, int> CreateDelegate(string method)
    => (Action<Dog, int>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<Dog, int>),
                                                 typeof(Dog).GetMethod(method));

public void applyToDogs(Action<Dog, int> func, int arg)
{
    foreach (Customer customer in Customers)
    {
        foreach (Dog dog in customer.Dogs)
        {
            func(dog, arg);
        }
    }
}
```

---

I suggest to create an enumerator like this, so that you can handle all kinds of methods and this is more efficient.

```
public void walkDogs(int walkTime)
{
    foreach (var dog in Dogs)
        dog.TakeForWalk(walkTime);
}

public void feedDogs(int amountOfFood)
{
    foreach (var dog in Dogs)
        dog.GiveFood(amountOfFood);
}

public IEnumerable<Dog> Dogs
{
    get
    {
        foreach (Customer customer in Customers)
        {
            foreach (Dog dog in customer.Dogs)
            {
                yield return dog;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @shingo! I definitely learned a lot from your answer.
I wasn't aware of the possibility to create enumerators before.

And I might need some time to fully understand the `CreateDelegate(string method)` part, but I do like the approach 

Answer (score 1):

it can be something like this

```
public class DogWalker
{
    public IEnumerable<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    public DogWalker()
    {
    }

    public void walkDogs(int walkTime)
    {
        applyToDogs((dog, args) => dog.TakeForWalk((int)args[0]), new object[] { walkTime });
    }

    public void feedDogs(int amountOfFood)
    {
        applyToDogs((dog, args) => dog.GiveFood((int)args[0]), new object[] { amountOfFood });
    }

    #region Helper Method
    public void applyToDogs(Action<Dog, object[]> action, object[] args)
    {
        foreach (Customer customer in Customers)
        {
            foreach (Dog dog in customer.Dogs)
            {
                action(dog, args);
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).